Is there a way that I could switch plotting methods using a button in Tkinter?
I know this is a long shot, but I have an application that would plot n spectra (counts per energy) and I want to have the option to visualise them as normal spectra or histograms.
Is there a way that I could detect which method is currently being used and use a Toggle button that would switch to the other plotting method? I'm using plt.plot for the first and plt.step for the other.
I was able to do the same thing for the x and y scales using something like this:
    def toggle_xscale(self):
        """Toggle the x-axis scale between linear and logarithmic."""
        current_scale = self.plot_axes.get_xscale()
        new_scale = 'log' if current_scale == 'linear' else 'linear'
        self.plot_axes.set_xscale(new_scale)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()  # Redraw the canvas

    def toggle_yscale(self):
        """Toggle the y-axis scale between linear and logarithmic."""
        current_scale = self.plot_axes.get_yscale()
        new_scale = 'log' if current_scale == 'linear' else 'linear'
        self.plot_axes.set_yscale(new_scale)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()  # Redraw the canvas

In my custom toolbar class from NavigationToolbar2Tk. Can anyone help?
I guess I'm expecting some similar function to the one that I showed extracting the plotting method and changing it.

Your functions are already detecting which method is currently being used. You can now simply add two buttons - and their command attrs - to call these methods.
class YourClass(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.toggle_xscale_btn = tk.Button(self, text='Toggle XSCALE', command=self.toggle_xscale)
        self.toggle_xscale_btn.pack()
        self.toggle_yscale_btn = tk.Button(self, text='Toggle YSCALE', command=self.toggle_yscale)
        self.toggle_yscale_btn.pack()
        # Other self attributes and packed widgets.

    def toggle_xscale(self):
        """Toggle the x-axis scale between linear and logarithmic."""
        pass

    def toggle_yscale(self):
        """Toggle the y-axis scale between linear and logarithmic."""
        pass


Yes I know, this was already done. I'm asking if there's a way to do the same thing to figure out which method is being used for the plotting part.
it's either plt.plot(...) or plt.step(...) and I cannot seem to find anything that would give me back this information, nor the ability to change it if I want to. I want to add an extra button toggle_mode_btn to alternate between the two methods

I suggest that you keep track of the plot type, e.g., plot_type == 1 means line plot, plot_type == 0 means histogram, and
def toggle_plot_type(self, plot_type):
    plot_type = 1 - plot_type
    if plot_type:
        # line plot
    else:
        # histogram
    return plot_type

in the main program
    type_plot = 1
    # line plot
    

and in the interaction loop
    plot_type = toggle_plot_type(plot_type)

